# Is it possible to write javascript in php heredoc syntax?

Tags: javascript, php, heredoc

I'm trying to output Javascript code heredoc syntax and I want it to be printed out with the PHP `print_r` function. Is it possible to do that?

PHP:

```
<?php
function printR($val){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($val);
    echo "</pre>";
}

$str = <<<EOT
    var msg = "Hello my name is ";
    var name = "Jermaine Forbes";
    function writeIt(m,n){
        console.log(m+n);
    }
    writeIt(msg,name);
    EOT;

printR($str);
?>
```

*(by @FirstOne: I kept `EOT;` idented since there was* a comment about it)*

Comment: TimoSta yes, and I got an error saying " unexpected end of file on line 50"

Comment: Even if you could, this would not be good practice

Comment: I deleted my comment and expanded it into an answer. @George why would it not be good practice?

Comment: It's bad practice because you can just output Javascript directly, outside of PHP tags.  I would hate to maintain code written in this manner and would almost certainly re-write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  If you expect to have only Javascript in the string (no PHP variable), I would use nowdoc instead of heredoc (use single quotes around the opening `EOT`

```
$str = <<<'EOT'
            var msg = "Hello my name is ";
            var name = "Jermaine Forbes";
            function writeIt(m,n){

              console.log(m+n);
            }

            writeIt(msg,name);

EOT;
```

Note also that the closing delimiter must be alone on the final line. You can't have any space before or after it. Your code didn't work because you have indented `EOT;`.  [From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> Warning: It is very important to note that the line with the closing
>   identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;).
>   That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and
>   there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

Comment: I'm not trying output the javascript so it can perform the function. I'm trying to print it out so that you can see the javascript on the web page. Someone edited my description, so people are unsure as to what I wanted to do

Comment: Ok I understand and I've removed my closing statement. Was the answer helpful in resolving your issue? If so upvote & select it. Otherwise, let me know how it falls short so I can learn to write better answers.